# Java threads - start() and run() - lost line in console

Tags: java, multithreading

Why is another "TaskImpl run()" in Scenario 1 below missing ?

Scenario 1: if the line marked with 1. is before the line marked with 2. this is shown in the console:

> TaskImpl run()
>   ThreadImpl run()
>   ThreadImpl run()
>   Finished

Scenario 2: If the line marked with 2. is before the line marked with 1. this is shown in the console:

> TaskImpl run()
>   TaskImpl run()
>   ThreadImpl run()
>   ThreadImpl run()
>   Finished

My code :

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Thread t1 = new ThreadImpl();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TaskImpl());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.run();   // 1.
        t2.run();   // 2. 

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}

class ThreadImpl extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("ThreadImpl run()");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class TaskImpl implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("TaskImpl run()");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you ever print `TaskImpl run()` ?  I don't see this.

Comment: Here @TimBiegeleisen: 
`class ThreadImpl extends Thread 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            **System.out.println("ThreadImpl run()");**`

Comment: Why are you calling `Thread.run()` directly?

Comment: This happens because `t1.run()` takes more time than `t2.start();`. [`Thread#run`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.run%28%29) checks if the `target` is not `null` (see the source of that class) and a [thread sets `target` to `null`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.exit%28%29) if the thread has done its job and "exits". So the call `t2.run();` fails the `target != null` check. Sorry I don't have time to write an answer :).

Comment: @Tom This sounds on the money.  Basically he is generating _two_ calls to the `run()` method of each thread.  One is asynchronous and indirect (`start()`) and the other is synchronous and direct (`run()`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And the second `t2.run();` happens after the corresponding thread exits, because of the prior `t1.run();` call which blocks the main thread for 2 seconds.

Comment: Ok, found the time to write an answer. I guess it is a bit clearer than a short comment :D.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the implementation of [`Thread#run`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.run%28%29) the `run` method of the `target` (the `Thread` implementation/subclass which should be run in a thread) will only be called if `target` is not `null`:

> ```
> @Override
> public void run() {
>     if (target != null) {
>         target.run();
>     }
> }
> ```

Now another info: If a thread has done its job it calls the [*private* `exit`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.exit%28%29) method which sets `target` to `null` (*):

> ```
> private void exit() {
>     // [omitted code lines]
>
>     /* Aggressively null out all reference fields: see bug 4006245 */
>     target = null;
>
>     // [omitted code lines]
> }
> ```

So if you called `start` on a Thread and it has done its job, then you can't call `run` again ... well you can, but I won't do much.

Now let's look at your first version of your code:

```
t1.start(); -> starts a thread; takes at least 2 seconds to finish
t2.start(); -> starts a thread; takes at least 1 second to finish

t1.run(); -> blocks main thread; takes at least 2 seconds to finish
t2.run(); -> called after `t1.run()` finished;
```

So as you can see, `t2.run()` will run at least 2 seconds *after* `t2.start()` because `t1.run()` blocks the method call. So `t2` (from `t2.start()`) already finished and set `target` to `null` so `t2.run()` fails the `target != null` check and does "nothing".

Now the second version:

```
t1.start(); -> starts a thread; takes at least 2 seconds to finish
t2.start(); -> starts a thread; takes at least 1 second to finish

t2.run(); -> blocks main thread; takes at least 1 seconds to finish
t1.run(); -> called after `t2.run()` finished;
```

Here `t2.run()` can run before `t2` from `t2.start()` could have finished his "sleep" so `target` is still set correctly.
And `t1.run()` also has no problem, because it directly calls the *overriden* `run` method of `ThreadImpl`, so it doesn't need to pass the check. And it wouldn't have a problem to pass it anyway, because `t2.run()` sleeps for 1 second, so `t1` from `t1.start()` still sleeps for another second and his `target` is also still set.
That is why you get the "full" output.

I hope my explanation is clear and you understand the cause for the different output :).

(*) Please mind that this behavior my vary in other Java Environments. But the Oracles version and OpenJDK are doing that.

Comment: You might want to add that setting `target` to null upon thread exit is an implementation detail and could vary across JVM implementations.

Comment: There's another reason why `t1.run()` has no problem.  You showed how `Thread#run()` does nothing after the thread has been started, and allowed to run to completion; but `t1.run()` never calls `Thread#run()`.  It calls the OP's `ThreadImpl#run()` method which does not have the same restriction.

Comment: @jameslarge, this is correct. 't1.run()' directly calls the overriden method, whereas 't2.run()' calls the "original" version.

Comment: Thanks to everyone especially Tom.

Comment: @Slipknot You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you to solve your problem/question.